# Working with integrals and matrices- beginner question

Tags: self-study, missing-data, integral

In the book *[Analysis of Incomplete Multivariate Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412040611)* (Schafer, 1997), the writer tells about the following model: $Y$ is our data with missing entries, divided to $Y_{mis}$ and $Y_{obs}$, the missing and observable entry set. $R$ is an indicator variable matrix indicating for each entry of $Y$ if it's missing or not. $Y$ and $R$ depend on hidden variables:  $\theta$ is data generating hidden parameter(s), and $\xi$ is the missing data parameter(s).

Can someone explain the integrals? Specifically, I want to know:

1. What are the rules used between equalities?
2. Intuitive reasoning about differentiating on non-trivial variable, such as $Y_{mis}$? How should I think about it?

> **2.3 The observed-data likelihood and posterior**
>
> *2.3.1 Observed-data likelihood*
>   Following arguments given by Rubin (1976) and Little and Rubin (1987), it can be shown that under ignorability, we do not need to consider the model for $R$ nor the nuisance parameters $ξ$ when making likelihood-based or Bayesian inferences about $θ$.
>
> Because the observed data truly consist not only of Y obs,
>   but also of R, the probability distribution of the observed data
>   is actually given by
>
> \begin{align}
> P(R, Y_{obs}|θ, ξ) &= \int P(R, Y| θ, ξ)  dY_{mis}  \\
>                    &= \int P(R|Y, ξ)P(Y|θ) dY_{mis},  \tag{2.3}
> \end{align}
>
> where the integral is understood to mean summation for distributions that are discrete.

Comment: What does your second question refer to here?  I don't see anything being differentiated.  And what does "non-trivial" mean?

Comment: I meant the integration variable, nontrivial means non-scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is based on the defintion of a marginal and conditional distributions such that 
\begin{align*}
p(y)=\int p(y,x)dx=\int p (y|x)p (x)dx
\end{align*}

Marginal distributions interact with conditional distributions such that:
\begin{align*}
p(y|z)=\int p(y,x|z)dx=\int p (y|x,z)p (x|z)dx
\end{align*}

In your case under ignorablity assumption (MAR assumption and distinct parameter space) $f (r|y; \xi ) = f (r |y_{obs} ;\xi )$ you  can impute successfully and  obtain correct likelihood or Bayes inferences about the parameters without modeling the missingness

Comment: Thank you. For future readers I'll say what helped me: write down the bayes rule for discrete summation, then move to integral case, and apply as needed.